# How to add columns to wordpress menu editor

Tags: menus, navigation, columns

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to add columns and headings to sub menus. Naturally I want to create a basic megamenu where I can add titles with links inside  elements. With list below the items.

I've done a quick mockup on [codepen](http://codepen.io/Five50/pen/aNVyYV) of what I'm trying to achieve under the services link.

Please not I'm working to avoid megamenu plugins because of the unneeded bloat.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with default WordPress menu system and CSS.

When you add item to your menu, Make this hierarchy:

```
- Services
     - Social Welfare
        |- Funeral Service
        |- Food Bank
```

Then go with CSS

```
ul.menu > li > ul > li { /* the CSS for column */
    /* You can use combination of float: left; and width: 20% to get 5 column. */
} 
ul.menu > li > ul > li li {} /* the CSS for items inside column */
```

Comment: Cheers, Tung Du. I already know how to do it in CSS. I'm just looking to change the markup to reflect the flow of the nav. So using h2/h3 tags and adding columns which don't hold an anchor.

Comment: I think the simplest way to get mega menu is to style 2nd level `a` tag as heading. You can even disble the pointer when hover on it, change from pointer to cursor. If you don't satisfy, you can go with custom nav walker to get the change in markup.